# Ambiguous call to operator new[] when upgrading to C++ 20

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++20, new-operator

I am getting an error when compiling the following code after upgrading from C++17 to C++20 with msvc:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
void alloc(void* dest)
{
    using ty = decltype(new T);
    reinterpret_cast<ty&>(dest) = new T;
}

int main() 
{
    int obj[5][10];
    alloc<decltype(obj)>(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>(7): error C2668: 'operator new[]': ambiguous call to overloaded function
predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(58): note: could be 'void *operator new[](size_t)'
predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(33): note: or       'void *operator new(size_t)'
<source>(7): note: while trying to match the argument list '(unsigned __int64)'
<source>(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void alloc<int[5][10]>(void *)' being compiled
```

(This is a minimal repro, when I remove the tuple include then it compiles however I can't just remove the include in the real code).

Using C++ insights I can see that the c++ 17 was doing what I expected, the template substitution generated `new int[5UL][10];` for `new T`.

I'm not sure why this is now ambiguous in C++ 20, and how I can specify what version of new I need.

Comment: I think that's probably a bug of msvc... gcc can do so, and it seems that C++20 doesn't change related things in operator new. Including a header causes this is also never expected.

Comment: Probably only a result of forming the minimal repro, however `reinterpret_cast<ty&>(dest) = new T` is an aliasing violation and has undefined behavior, because it accesses the `void*` pointer `dest` itself as if it was a an object of type `int(*)[10]`. It also won't have any side effect outside the function. The way `alloc` is used in `main` makes no sense.

Comment: The error message makes no sense as user code never calls any of the `operator new` functions (the `new` operator is not  one).

Comment: Most likely it's a bug, reduced: https://godbolt.org/z/rKq55nq3z

Comment: I have a question though, what on earth that code is supposed to do. You cast a pointer to an array to pointer to void, and then cast it to a reference ..to a pointer? Then write write pointer value to an array?  THis is not UB only if array is of `char` and you use pointer to char in cast, not a reference (it's implementation defined how references are stored). And so far you would be much better off if you use placement new instead or write your own placement new overload.

Comment: Such errors popping up when you include certain headers... clear signs from Microsoft compiler that your code is trying to summon Cthulhu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a compiler bug.

In your instantiation of `new T` the allocated type is `T` and is an array type. Consequently only `operator new[]` should be looked up for the new-expression's allocation function. This has been the case since the first C++ standard and is still the case. So `void *operator new(size_t)` shouldn't even be a candidate to consider in the supposedly-ambiguous overload resolution.

However the code does have undefined behavior, see my comment under the question.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, I've logged a bug report on the developer community here: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-ambiguous-call-to-operator-new/10426338

And yep as your comment suggested I unintentionally added the UB in the example, the real code is different, I just got it to the point where I was seeing the same error and didn't compile it with ub warnings enabled. 康桓瑋 in the comments posted a better minimal repro than I did.

Thanks!